# Wrapper function for unknown formula

Tags: java, python, function

Is there a way to create a function as below?

I need to calculate the area of triangle, and I don't remember the right formula to calculate this and there is no internet or other sources of some information to me. What I do remember is that arguments for such function are some side **b** and height **h**. So I want to create some function which would look like this:

```
public static void calculate(String forgottenFunc, int... params) {/*implementation*/};
```

I thought of implementing based on JavaScript eval function from Java, withough using RegExp. I've got stuck on converting string (forgottenFunc) to some real function that would use given parametrs to calculate what I need. Or any alternatives on Python's eval or some other feature.
Thanks

Comment: To calculate the area of a triangle, use A = bh/2

Comment: I don't think you tried to find an answer.  There are many different ways of calculating the area of a triangle, wikipedia provides [10 separate sections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Computing_the_area_of_a_triangle) on the different ways this can be done.

Comment: I think "calculate the area of a triangle" is just an example.  What John gray is really asking is does java have closures.

Comment: I don't need to calculate area of a triangle, what i need is to parse some formula from string format to actual actual function

Comment: maybe [Using Java Reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Jep](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jep/), a free Java math parser.

Answer (score 1):

[mXparser](http://mathparser.org/) will fit your needs :-) Please follow below example:

```
import org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.*;
...
...
public static double calculate(String forgottenFunc, double... params) {
    Function f = new Function(forgottenFunc);
    return f.calculate(params);
}
...
...
System.out.println( calculate("p(a,h) = a*h/2", 2, 3) );
```

Result:

```
3.0
```

Please follow [mXparser tutorial](http://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/)

Additionally - this software is using mXparser as well - you can learn the syntax [Scalar](https://scalarmath.org) [Calculator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mathparser.scalar.lite) [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mathparser.scalar.pro)

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I see that you want a parser, not a closure.

There is no built-in equivalent of the JavaScript eval function.  It is considered evil.

You can either use a third party parser like [zovegames suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10272413/348975) or build your own using something like [javacc](http://javacc.java.net/).

Answer (score 0):

For a general solution: you could embed [MVEL](http://mvel.codehaus.org/) in your program, pass the formula as a string, bind the parameters and evaluate it. From the linked page:

> MVEL is a powerful expression language for Java-based applications. It provides a plethora of features and is suited for everything from the smallest property binding and extraction, to full blown scripts.